# How to get the Time Difference between two time value in php

Tags: php

My question is, How can i compute the difference between to time value without getting a negative output. I have no problem in computing the time difference but the problem comes when the time is like this:

timein : 23:00 *Note: m_time is timein*

timeout: 08:00  *Note: mx_time is timeout*

Here's my code that can get the time difference:

```
$start_time = explode(":",$m_time);   //where m_time = 10:32
$start_time_hr = $start_time[0];
$start_time_min = $start_time[1];
$start_tot_min = intval($start_time_hr*60) + $start_time_min;

$end_time = explode(":",$mx_time);   //where mx_time = 11:45

$end_time_hr = $end_time[0];
$end_time_min = $end_time[1];

$end_tot_min = intval($end_time_hr*60) + $end_time_min; //converting hour to min + min

$total_min_diff = intval($end_tot_min - $start_tot_min);

hr_diff = intval($total_min_diff/60);    
min_diff = intval($total_min_diff%60);


<?php echo "The total Difference Is : ".$hr_diff." Hours & ".$min_diff." Minutes.";?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest to add day (24 hour) when find out the time out hour is smaller than time in hour.

```
$start_time = explode(":",$m_time);
$start_time_hr = $start_time[0];
$start_time_min = $start_time[1];
$start_tot_min = intval($start_time_hr*60) + $start_time_min;

$end_time = explode(":",$mx_time);
$end_time_hr = $end_time[0];

// Add a day if end time smaller than start time
if($end_time_hr<$start_time_hr){
    $end_time_hr += 24;
}

$end_time_min = $end_time[1];
$end_tot_min = intval($end_time_hr*60) + $end_time_min; //converting hour to min + min

$total_min_diff = intval($end_tot_min - $start_tot_min);

$hr_diff = intval($total_min_diff/60);    
$min_diff = intval($total_min_diff%60);
```

Hope this help :D

Answer (score 1):

Convert both the time to seconds and then take the differnce and then convert the difference which is in seconds to Hour, Minutes.